# Unexpected token ILLEGAL only for certain Soundcloud sets

Tags: json, soundcloud

I'm creating a simple soundcloud app which streams a playlist/set via the API. For one playlist it works perfectly fine, while another returns 'unexpected token illegal'. Any help would be appreciated.

This soundcloud set returns 'unexpected token illegal': http://jsfiddle.net/zssfuutk/

```
<div id="wrap" v-component="plangular" v-src="'https://soundcloud.com/noonpacific/sets/midnight'">
```

While this soundcloud set works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/zssfuutk/1/

```
<div id="wrap" v-component="plangular" v-src="'https://soundcloud.com/noonpacific/sets/beach'">
```

Comment: 1. the URLs that you have in your code require authorisation, so noone can debug it but you (or whoever can login); 2. this error means that JSON tat is returned from the server is invalid

Comment: @akonsu you shouldn't need authorization to access these, they're public sets. Just trying to diagnose why the response from the server would be invalid for one set, but not the other. thanks for the help.